# What is wrong with my use of the Ribbon control in a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, ribboncontrolslibrary

I have added a reference to `RibbonControlsLibrary.dll`.  v4.0.0.11019. Then, I have the namespace declaration in my main window:

```
xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
```

Then I try and use the ribbon in the top row of my main, outer, grid:

```
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<r:Ribbon Title="ModuleRibbon" Grid.Row="0">
    <r:RibbonTab></r:RibbonTab>
    <r:RibbonTab></r:RibbonTab>
</r:Ribbon>
```

All this gives me is a compile error stating:

> Error 25  The tag 'Ribbon' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary'.
>   Line 22 Position 10.

Every tutorial and guide I have found says to do what I have done. There are no Google results for the error message - minus the Line and Position and other project specific info.

Help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to MSDN Ribbon controls are in `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` assembly and not `RibbonControlsLibrary` as in your example. Declare your namespace like below and it should work:

```
xmlns:r="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"
```

Answer (score 5):

The XML namespace that you have used will only work with the Ribbon Control library that is downloaded separately from the .NET Framework... I believe that you can still download that version from the [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF October 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=11877) page on MSDN. This was the only way to use the Ribbon Control library before it was included in the Framework version 4.5.

If you are using the Ribbon Control library that *is* included with the .NET Framework, then you should use the following XML namespace:

> xmlns:Ribbon="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon"

Comment: It was the separate download, but I will now try with the 4.5 one and the namespace you give.

Comment: I am currently using the separate downloaded dll (version 4.0.0.11019) and I use exactly the XML namespace that you showed in your question without problem. You're not developing on a network drive are you... that could be the cause of your problem. If you can build your project and make the error disappear temporarily, then that is another sign of the network drive problem.

Comment: I discovered the project was targeting 3.5 for some accidental reason, so I didn't see the Ribbon reference. Having fixed that and used the correct declaration, all is fine.